# Django Rest Framework's serializer.is_valid() raising validation errors even though required=false

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to have these fields optional in my form but...

#### Error:

```
{"name":["This field may not be blank."],"email":["This field may not be blank."]}
```

#### Serializer:

```
class StudentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    name = CharField(read_only=False, required=False, allow_null=True)
    user = StudentUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    invite = StudentInviteSerializer(read_only=True)

    email = CharField(read_only=False, required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'user', 'invite', 'email')
```

Comment: can you add the view / viewset?

Comment: I think that would be obfuscating the question as it's has quite a lot added. But I'm very confident that it's not the problem as the important parts are all still in there, up until the validation error upon calling serializer.is_valid()

Comment: It depends on how you actually instantiate the serializer ( this might seem weird if you're using generics,) Adding partial = True to the instatiation of the serializer would most likely solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think it would as all the attributes are sent in the json string even though they are blank. The default update mixin's mechanism for determining it it should be "partial" or not is also still in place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding `allow_blank=True` in your serializer's `name` and `email` fields.

```
name = CharField(read_only=False, required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)

email = CharField(read_only=False, required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
```

From http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield

> `max_length` - Validates that the input contains no more than this number of characters.
>   `min_length` - Validates that the input contains no fewer than this number of characters.
>   `allow_blank` - If set to True then the empty string should be considered a valid value. If set to False then the empty string is considered invalid and will raise a validation error. Defaults to False.
>   `trim_whitespace` - If set to True then leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed. Defaults to True.
>   The `allow_null` option is also available for string fields, although its usage is discouraged in favor of `allow_blank`. It is valid to set both `allow_blank=True` and `allow_null=True`, but doing so means that there will be two differing types of empty value permissible for string representations, which can lead to data inconsistencies and subtle application bugs.

Comment: Yes, it is and it worked! Turns out that I had the wrong kwarg! For CharField it's "allow_blank", not "required".

Comment: Please check this link. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield